# How to load sales collection for one day (24 hours)?

Tags: php, magento

I am using following code to get the sales data of the single day, what should I pass in the to and from variables for the to and from time?
Date format used is 11/15/14 (mm/dd/yy)

I am passing 00:00:00 but this is for the midnight.

```
$to_date = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', strtotime($to));
$from_date = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', strtotime($from));

    $orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
                             ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following code

```
$to_date = date('Y-m-d' . ' 23:59:00', strtotime($to));
$from_date = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', strtotime($from));    

$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
                       ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this in my localhost and it is working fine, you can adjust the filter as per your needed.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$time = time();
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time); echo '<br>';
$lastTime = $time - 86400; // 60*60*24
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);


$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 'complete');


//echo $orders->getSelect();
echo '<pre>';

$_totalData = $orders->getData();
//echo $_grand = $_totalData['0']['grand_total'];

//print_r($_totalData);

foreach ($_totalData as $data) {
    $total_sale[] = $data['grand_total'];
}

print_r($total_sale);
```

Please comment here if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use current date with 24 hours timespan format and use the limit between 0 to 24 hour for that day

Comment: $to and $from will be dynamic dates may be past dates also

Comment: See Idea Given by @Ashique C m that is what i was saying InputDay would be your current date. $to_date would be time span which start with 0 mean from starting of the day and $from_date would be your last time for that day.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get record for single day, so there is need of only one single day as input. See the code below:

```
$inputDay = "17-11-2014";
$from_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$inputDay 00:00:00"));
$to_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$inputDay 23:59:59"));
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
                         ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' => $from_date))
                         ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' => $to_date));
```

I'm passing single day and calculating the start time and end time simple!

Comment: It is not returning any result

Comment: Updated the same, try again :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to change in your data format to make this for 24 hours

```
  $inputDay = "11/13/14"; // your current format for data is mm/dd/yy
$inputDay = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($inputDay)); 

$to_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($inputDay)).' 23:59:59';
$from_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($inputDay)).' 00:00:00';

// Now data is become Y-m-d h:i:s
 $orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
             ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date));


  echo $orders->getSize();
    exit;
```

hope this will sure work for you.

Comment: it is giving zero results